# commons-logging lost in spring-core in maven?

Tags: java, spring, maven

Below is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <properties>
        <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
        <spring.version>4.1.6.RELEASE</spring.version>

    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

I can print the dependency tree by 'mvn dependency:tree'

```
\- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |     \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
```

You can see the the **commons-logging** is under the **spring-core**.

But when I changed to below.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <properties>
        <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
        <spring.version>4.1.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.spring.platform</groupId>
                <artifactId>platform-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.2.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

And print the following tree.

```
INFO] \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |     \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
```

You can find that the **commons-logging** is lost.

I can click into the child of the **spring-webmvc** in IDE and confirm that the **commons-logging** exists in **spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.pom**.

I ran into this issue because I want to exclude the **commons-logging** from **spring** and plan to use **jcl-over-slf4j**. So why the commons-logging jar file is lost when I use the **io.spring.platform**. Thanks.

Comment: It is not recommedate to use `commons-logging` according the [doc](https://docs.spring.io/platform/docs/Cairo-SR7/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-logging)

Answer (score 0):

By importing a pom, you apply the dependencyManagement in that pom, but also the dependencyManagement from it's parent and it's parent's parent etc.

The spring platform-bom:1.1.2.RELEASE extends from [spring-boot-starter-parent:1.2.3.RELEASE](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/1.2.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-1.2.3.RELEASE.pom). And in that parent pom there's a dependencyManagement part that already excludes the commons-logging:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```